# How convert string with current GMT time zone to to normal date time

Tags: java, string, datetime

The string i'm having is

```
Mon Mar 04 12:19:50 GMT+05:30 2019
```

and i want it converted to

```
2019-03-04T12:19:50
```

I tried doing:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

 Date d1 = null;
 try{
     d1 = sdf3.parse(String.valueOf(currentTime));    
 }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

 System.out.println("check..." + d1);
```

But this doesn't work

How can i do this?
Please help me figure out the logic.

Comment: And what time zone would `1:14` be equivalent to for `12:19 GM+5:30T`?

Comment: Hey i've just given a example of 1:14 if in the string it's 12:19 i want 12:19 only

Comment: Do you absolutely need `java.util.Date`? If you can *possibly* use the `java.time` package instead, I'd very strongly recommend that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon Skeet mentioned, using `java.time` is a good idea. Use `Date.toInstant`, and convert into a `LocalDateTime`, at your offset :

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SO201904030814 {

    public SO201904030814() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date d1 = sdf3.parse(String.valueOf("Mon Mar 04 12:19:50 GMT+05:30 2019"));

        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d1.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));

        System.out.println("check..." + d1 + " vs " + dateTime);

    }

}
```

HTH!

Comment: Well, if you can use `java.time` classes anyway, it'd be better to just use `DateTimeFormatter` and parse it to a `ZonedDateTime` directly. Instead of relying on the broken `SimpleDateFormat` (even if it works in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is parse the `String`

```
String value = "Mon Mar 04 12:19:50 GMT+05:30 2019";
DateTimeFormatter formatIn = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, formatIn);
```

Now you can format the value to your needs

```
DateTimeFormatter formatOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = zdt.format(formatOut);
// 2019-03-04T12:19:50
```

or

```
String formatted = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
// 2019-03-04T12:19:50
```

but if I was going to do that, I'd probably do something like...

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId).toLocalDateTime();
String formatted = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
// 2019-03-04T17:49:50
```

Then it's in the current timezone

I recommend that you take a look at [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)